# can I do independent subscribe/publish with Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, publish-subscribe

Suppose I have some class MyClass. In one part of my code I want something like this:

```
Observable.Subscribe<MyClass>(myClass => DoSomething(myClass));
```

Then in another place (file/project/time) I have something like this:

```
Observable.Publish(instanceOfMyClass);
```

This second line triggers all the methods that were subscribed with that exact class type. Is this something that the Reactive Extensions (v1 or v2) supports?

It would be useful to specify a SynchronizationContext as part of the Subscribe call. It would also be nice to specify there whether or not the method should be held with a WeakReference. And the Publish method should have the ability to do it all synchronously or give me something I can wait on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wouldn't be hard to create.

You just need an internal `Dictionary<Type, Object>` and use it to store each `Subject<T>` (as the object) by `Type`.

You can then just write the two `Subscribe` and `Publish` methods to work off of the internal dictionary.

Should be quite simple in fact.

---

Rather than just say it was simple I thought I'd give it a go.

Here's my Rx Pub/Sub class:

```
public static class RxPS
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> _subjects
        = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(Action<T> observer)
    {
        lock(_subjects)
        {
            if (!_subjects.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            {
                _subjects.Add(typeof(T), new Subject<T>());
            }
            return (_subjects[typeof(T)] as Subject<T>)
                .Subscribe(observer);
        }
    }

    public static void Publish<T>(T item)
    {
        lock(_subjects)
        {
            if (_subjects.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            {
                (_subjects[typeof(T)] as Subject<T>)
                    .OnNext(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how it is used:

```
RxPS.Publish(1);
var d = RxPS.Subscribe<int>(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); 
RxPS.Publish(2);
d.Dispose();
RxPS.Publish(3);
```

The result is that this code will write `2` to the console only.

Enjoy!

Comment: Explain to me "OnNext" ? Is that going to trigger multiple subscribers? And what happens if I let "d" go out of scope? Will it dispose when the garbage collector comes 'round or not?

Comment: Calling `OnNext` gives the subject the next value for its own observable sequence and this value will be sent to any and all subscribers of the subject. Nothing will happen if you let `d` go out of scope. The GC will collect the variable, but it never ever calls `Dispose` so it won't cancel any subscription. Calling `Dispose` is always the programmer's responsibility. In the case of Rx you only call `Dispose` if you want to cancel the subscription early, i.e. before `OnCompleted` or `OnError` is naturally called.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for something like ReactiveUI's [MessageBus class](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/MessageBus.cs). This class uses Rx to implement a publish/subscribe model, basically by just having a Dictionary of Type => IObservables.

Comment: Broken link: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/MessageBus.cs